# How to set a workspace in File GDB, ArcGIS

Tags: python-2.7, gis

I am creating a script that creates a new, empty File GDB and FeatureDataset but I don't know how to set that all outputs of script would be automatically saved in File GDB or Feature Dataset. Now I am using an interface so that the user has to specify the output for all analysis but because I have a lot of outputs I would like to reduce the number of outputs in interface (example point, line, poly,….). 
Example:

```
import arcpy
GDB_Location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
GDB_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
GDB_file = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(GDB_Location, GDB_name)
out_dataset_path = GDB_file
out_dataset_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
feature_dataset = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(out_dataset_path,out_dataset_name)
point= arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
line = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
poly = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
```

….

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you want to have in your code:

1. A step that creates the geodatabase
2. A variable that you can use in subsequent steps to refer to that geodatabase

The ArcPy functions that *create* a geodatabase (GDB) or feature dataset don't simultaneously generate variables. Think of that as two separate steps, and then you'll be able to have a variable for that output workspace.

```
import arcpy
import os

GDB_Location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
GDB_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# function to create the GDB
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(GDB_Location, GDB_name)
# variable to refer to the GDB
gdb = os.path.join(GDB_Location, GDB_name)

dataset_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
# function to create the dataset
arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb, dataset_name)
# variable to refer to the dataset
dataset = os.path.join(gdb, dataset_name)
```

If you want to reduce the number of input parameters that the user needs to fill out, it's possible to generate names yourself in code — that decision really depends on what the end user wants.

An "in between" alternative is to [provide a default value](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//00150000000n000000.htm) that suggests what the user might want to use. That way they can choose the easy way (use the default values) or do a little more work to customize the output feature names.

```
# EITHER have user provide the output feature class name
pointName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
# OR name the points yourself
pointName = "output_point"

# and then concatenate that together with the geodatabase and feature dataset
pointFeature = os.path.join(gdb, dataset, pointName)
# then use variable "pointFeature" in subsequent functions to create that feature
```